# Visual Studio 2013 Service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, visual-studio-2013

I need to access an old wsdl webservice in a Windows Store app.
Now Visual Studio 2013 creates the reference for me.

One problem is, that VS doesn't create EventHanlders and non-async methods for me.

Can somebody tell me why, or how i can get VS to generate like before?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a web reference instead of Service reference. To do that add a service reference, click on advance, and then here you will find a web reference button then you should be able to get wht you are looking for.

It is just a first overview for you to see if that solve; it may or may not help.

Comment: A fairly good idea. Unfortunatly, there is no "web reference" button in my Visual Studio 2013. By the way, I'm using a Visual Studio Express Edition.

Comment: Like I said, in my VS there is no "web reference button" in the advanced dialog. Maybe this happens because I doesn't target the .Net 2.0 Framework. I will try again, but I think that your answer is correct.